# Target child UL with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an unordered list on my page containing lists within each LI.

Currently they're all set to display none, but on click Id like to toggle the display setting.

Ive written the following only I cant seem to get it too work, has anybody an idea of where im going wrong?

```
//Product range expander
$('.product-range ul li a').click(function() {
  $(this).find('.product-range ul li ul').slideDown('slow');
  //$('.product-range ul li a').next('ul').toggle();
  return false;
});
```

Answer (score 3):

- Use `$(this)` to select the element which has been clicked on (ie, the anchor element).
- Use `.parents("li")` to find the first matching parent of the anchor. This is so we can then find the `ul` which is contained in the same `li` as the `a`.
- Use `.find("ul")` to find the `ul` element which is within the `li` element.

---

```
$('.product-range ul li a').click(function() {
  $(this).parents("li").find("ul").slideDown('slow')
  return false;
});
```

---

Alternatively you can use `siblings`:

```
$('.product-range ul li a').click(function() {
  $(this).siblings("ul").slideDown('slow')
  return false;
});
```

However I prefer to find the mutual parent, and then find the element, in case the markup changes.

Answer (score 1):

In your code `this` refers to the *anchor found with jQuery*. Underneath it you don't have UL > LI structure I assume. In order to find the correct element change it to:

```
//Product range expander
$('.product-range ul li a').click(function() {
    $('.product-range ul li ul').slideDown('slow');
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(this).find('ul').slideDown('slow');
```

should be enough to display the nested list/s.

Answer (score 0):

please try this.

```
$(this).children().find('ul').slideDown('slow');
```